# Can't understand "disava" word

Tags: listening

I can't understand one word in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC1Sb7IeSiM) video, time 1:18:

> ... Number two, and this is hugely important, dis??? yourself immediately ...

Can someone help me to identify the word?

Comment: -1 question shows no research effort before posting. Also voting to close Too Localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is "disavow."  It means *to break a connection with*.

The author is essentially saying, "If you think writing a book will be all fun, and little work, then *disavow* yourself of that silly, unrealistic notion."

Comment: That's pretty funny, since that is a poor choice of words for someone who purports to be a writer. The word she means in that context, I think, is *disabuse*: "Disabuse yourself of that notion."